# How to access clientAddress in Astro api routes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, server-side-rendering, astrojs

I know that we can access user's `IP` address in Astro using `Astro.clientAddress` value but this would only work in `.astro` pages.

```js
// your-ip.astro

---
const detectedIp = Astro.clientAddress;
---

<h1>
Your IP: {{ detectedIP }}
</h1>
```

but in my case, I have created a server-side API endpoint in Astro itself so like below.

```js
// pages/api/create-user.ts

export async function post({ request }) {
    console.log(await request.json());


    // I want to do like this in typescript endpoint file
    // const IP = Astro.clientAddress;


    return {
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: 'Astro',
            url: 'https://astro.build/',
            ip: `Your IP: {IP}`
        }),
    };
}
```

I want to access the user's `IP` address within this `typescript` file itself, but I think `Astro` is not provided in the `.ts` file context. So how to achieve that?

I looked at documentation around it but couldn't find out how to access that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the [`clientAddress`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#contextclientaddress) from the API context object in an endpoint function.

```
import type { APIContext } from 'astro';

export function get({ clientAddress }: APIContext) {
  return {
    body: `Your IP address is: ${clientAddress}`
  }
}
```